# rails has_one association preventing adding new child object if exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-one

In my rails app I have `user has_one :profile` and `profile belongs_to :user` association. If a user already has a profile and goes to the `user/:user_id/profile/new` page and submits a new profile, then the old profile gets updated.

I can prevent this with pundit (authorization gem) and authorize only users who don't have profile to be able to trigger new and create actions. I was wondering though what's the rails convention was in this case. I guess there should be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is rails convention. As you open same form on create and update, and if `profile.id` is `nil` form action will go to `Profile#create` and if `profile.id` is not `nil`, it will go to `Profile#update` action with the `profile.id` in the parameters.

Comment: Thanks Nermin, then I will use pundit.